# ubuntu a problem has occurred when checking for the update - 23.10

Tags: command-line, updates, 23.10

I installed Ubuntu 23.10.1 terminal worked normally untill I did reboot.
can't open ctrl + Alt + T, not from icon but it works from pycharm terminal.
problam is i cant user apps addicted on basic terminal. how can i fix it?

Comment: "problam is i cant user apps addicted on basic terminal" Explain please.

Comment: @OrganicMarble My suggested replacement for addicted is "added" or more correctly "that I installed from the terminal".

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.